# Nginx is breaking While showing images

Tags: django, nginx

I have high quality images which I want to show on my web page. But whenever am running with nginx the django project breaks after some time when pages are loading. I have checked all the file paths and images are loading in django without nginx

Tried to run in django was running bbut whenever nginx is configured webpage is breaking

Comment: What exactly broke? Can you provide more info than "it doesnt work"?

Comment: Loading of image is breaking. However it is resolved now. Thanks